# running two docker postgres service

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to run two postgres database with Docker service. I know they can't run on the same time, so I would like to change the port (not the `-p 5433: 5432`)

here's my script to start the docker service:

```
docker service create --name account-db --network account -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret_password -p 5432:5432 -d --mount type=volume,source=account,target=/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:latest
```

so if I want to run one on 5432 and another on 5433, how should I achieve that? thanks for any input / suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-p 5432:5432
```

This is the port mapping for the container. So for the first service, it should be

```
-p 5432:5432
```

And for the second service it should be

```
-p 5433:5432
```

The syntax is -p [port of the machine] : [port of the container]

Comment: are they not going to fight over the same tcp?

Comment: No. The port of the machine is what involves in the conflict. As long as you make it different. It works.

Answer (score 3):

[@vamsi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48702740/1924666) is right.

But when you are using a node port `xxxx`, you need to make sure that `xxxx` is available.

```
-p xxxx:5432
```

If you want to assign a free port automatically, use this

```
-p :5432
```

Leave node port empty `:5432`